# Is there any GUI tool to manipulate package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Wondering if there is any GUI tool to handle the command apt-get. I am using Ubuntu 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Synaptic package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto).

```
System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager
```

Keep in mind that this is [dropped](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/11/06/23/2134224/Synaptic-Dropped-From-Ubuntu-1110) from Ubuntu 11.10 onwards in favor of Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Synaptic would still be in the repository. 'sudo apt-get install synaptic' would install it.